# Internal Error when trying to access pgAdmin via kubectl proxy

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, kubectl, portforwarding

I've installed pgAdmin (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/runix/pgadmin4) in my k8s cluster. Using port-forwarding I can access the web interface of pgAdmin, but I want to use `kubectl proxy` instead of `kubectl port-forward` because when using port forwarding the connection is not stable enough (see the problems with `lost connection to pod`). So I hope `kubectl proxy` is more stable, but my problem is when I run `kubectl proxy` and try to access pgAdmin, I'm getting the following error in my browser:

`stream error: stream ID 5; INTERNAL_ERROR`

I'm using the following url to access pgAdmin: `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/pgadmin-pgadmin4:80/proxy`. Since the browser is already being redirected to `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/pgadmin-pgadmin4:80/proxy/login?next=%2F` (not the last part), I know that pgAdmin is working, but I've no idea how to solve the `INTERNAL ERROR` issue. When I check the console that runs the `kubectl proxy` command, the output is the following:

```
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
E0212 17:56:51.338567   41088 proxy_server.go:147] Error while proxying request: stream error: stream ID 5; INTERNAL_ERROR
```

Any idea how to fix this issue? An alternative would be to have a stable port-forwarding, but it seems that there's only the "while-true"-solution to restart the port-forwarding whenever the connection to the pod has been lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that few filters / rules are obstructing your access to pgAdmin from kubernettes cluster. This can be resolved by removing the filters. Use the below command for connecting pgAdmin without any filters.

```
kubectl proxy --address='0.0.0.0' --disable-filter=true
```

Comment: Yeah, that really seems to solve my issued. Thank you very much!